# Reducing costs on AMI snapshots

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, amazon-ebs

I am starting with AWS EC2 and I wanted to be able to spawn EC2 instances on-demand with some scripts ready to run and the necessary packages installed. I know that maybe using containers would be a good option, but this is not possible for now.

I have created a Lambda that creates an EC2 instance from a custom AMI where everything is installed. However, I would like to keep the EBS snapshot consumption to a minimum (below the Free Tier 1GB-month limit, preferably).

Is it possible to shrink my AMI's snapshot below the default 8GB? I also thought I could back my AMI in S3 instead of EBS storage, but further Googling seems to have proven me wrong.

Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: FYI these are snapshots of EBS volumes, not snapshots of AMIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMIs can only be stored the way they are.

Are there many? Do they differ? If they do not differ then use one AMI.

If minor variations make a baseline ami and then use userdata for the variation

Comment: I am only using one AMI, that's why I was trying to stay under the limit, and I am passing the startup commands over userdata. The cost is obviously negligible but is the only cost in my backend, so I was trying to avoid it, as it can actually grow undetected (while developing and updating the AMIs)

Comment: In that case not really anything you can do